# How to achieve consistent spacing in `derivative`s?

Tags: spacing, math-operators, kerning

When compiling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{derivative}


\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \[\pdv{P}{r}\]
    \[\pdv{T}{r}\]
    \[\pdv{X}{r}\]
\end{document}
```

one gets:

[image]

where it is clear that the `T` get spaced or kerned differently than the other letters.
I would like to ensure the `P` and the `X` are also kerned/spaced like the `T` in this example.

I believe I can insert `\!` spacings, but that can quickly become a nuisance if I decide to change font (where the kerning happens correctly somehow), or if `derivative` updates to address this issue.

**edit**: egreg's corrections

Comment: Welcome! Please, don't use `minimal` for examples, but rather `article`. Note also that `$$` should never be used in a LaTeX `document` environment.

Comment: I read that one should use `\partial\, y` in the numerator and `\partial x` in the denomiator.  It appears `\pdv` does that automatically.

Comment: You could use `\pdv[sep-inf-fun=1]{T}{r}` or `\pdv{\mkern1mu T}{r}` as they result in the same code. For a higher order derivative you would need to use `sep-ord-fun=1` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. Personally, I'm more of a fan of _reducing_ the spacing in the letters _other_ than the T.  Or is the philosophy to let d/dt act as an operator (like \log), meriting the space?

Comment: The package default of `\odv{y}{x}` is reducing to `\frac{dy}{dx}` without adding or removing any spacing, same for `\pdv` but with `\partial` instead of d. What you see is the default kerning between those characters. The package was made to give a simple and flexible way to consistently write derivatives. The philosophy behind the package default is to reproduce "the standard notation" (or rather a consistent notation) without adding or removing any spacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `derivative`. Look at the bounding boxes of P and T from the math symbol font:

[image]

Perhaps Knuth should have added a kern between `\partial` and `T`. He didn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\partial P$ $\partial T$

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

\fbox{\the\textfont1 P}
\fbox{\the\textfont1 T}

\end{document}
```

The tokens `\the\textfont1` point to the symbol font.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for this analysis. Could I manually add a kern between the symbols `\partial` and `P`, or otherwise modify kerning uniformly over a whole document? IIRC, `LuaLaTeX` allows this directly in some way, but I'm using `PdfLaTeX`.

Comment: @Matthias With `\partial\mkern1mu T`. I don't know what would happen with `derivative`.